# Array formula does not change reference cells

Tags: excel, array-formulas

#### My Data:

[image]

I am trying to replicate the answer/formula from `Column H`. This is an array formula, so I committed it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (*C+S+E* going forward).

**My formula** (in `H2`) **is:**

`=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$X$3:$X$94=Sheet4!A2,Sheet1!$AI$3:$AI$94))`

---

`Columns I:L` are different options I tried to replicate.

`Column I`: I highlighted the relevant cells, then put the above formula (from `H2`) in cell `I2`, and then used *C+S+E*. The result is **2** the entire way through.

Examining the differences between the formula between cells `H5` and `I5` shows that the reference `"Sheet4!A2"` is different.

- In `Column H`, the cell reference is `"Sheet4!A5"`, *which is **correct***.
- In `I5`, the reference is `"Sheet4!A2`, *which is **incorrect***.

To get past this, I tried to write the formula in `Column J`, and drag it down, which resulted in all errors.

`Columns K` and `L` are instances where I tried typing in the formula, highlighting my range, and then pressing *C+S+E*, either by hand (`Column K`), or moving between sheets and highlighting relevant references (`Column L`). The same issue arose.

I even tried highlighting `Column H`, editing `Cell H2`, and the hit *C+S+E*. I got the same result as I did in `Column I`.

I looked at [Excel Array Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513804/excel-array-formula) and [Excel: Array Formula Calculates Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061696/excel-array-formula-calculates-once), but those suggestions did not help me in this instance.

Automatic calculation is on in my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that when you have selected more than one cell, enter a formula and confirm with CSE, it is totally different than having just one cell selected, enter the formula and CSE.

In your scenario, you want to select just one cell. Enter the formula, confirm with CSE, then copy the formula down. The references that are preceded with a $ sign will stay the same. The references without a $ sign will be adjusted when the formula is copied.

You may want to refresh you knowledge about relative and absolute reference, for example [here](https://teylyn.com/2017/03/21/dollarsigns/)